# general backbone/marionette program structure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I need some general guidelines on how to structure a backbone/marionette application. Im very new to these frameworks and also to js in general.

Basically I have two pages and each page has a list. I have set up an application and a router for the application:

```
var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

app.module('Router', function(module, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    module.AppLayoutView = Marionette.Layout.extend({
        tagName: 'div',

        id: 'AppLayoutView',

        template: 'layout.html',

        regions: {
            'contentRegion' : '.main'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.initRouter();
        },

        ...
    });

    module.addInitializer(function() {
        var layout = new module.AppLayoutView();

        app.appRegion.show(layout);
    });
});
```

In the initRouter I have two functions, one for each page that gets called by router depending on the url.

The function for the content management page looks like this:

```
onCMNavigated: function(id) {
    var cMModule = App.module("com");
    var cM = new cMModule.ContentManagement({id: id, region: this.contentRegion});
    contentManagement.show();

    this.$el.find('.nav-item.active').removeClass('active');
    this.cM.addClass('active');
}
```

So if this is called, I create a new instance of ContentManagement model. In this model, when show() is called, I fetch the data from a rest api, and I parse out an array of banners that need to be shown in a list view. Is that ok? The model looks like the following:

```
cm.ContentManagement = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.id = options.id;
        this.region = options.region;
    },

    show: function() {
       var dSPage = new DSPage({id: this.id});

       dSPage.bind('change', function (model, response) {
          var view = new cm.ContentManagementLayoutView();

          this.region.show(view);
       }, this);

       dSPage.fetch({
         success: function(model, response) {
            // Parse list of banners and for each create a banner model
         }
    }
});

cm.ContentManagementLayoutView = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    id: 'CMLayoutView',

    className: 'contentLayout',

    template: 'contentmanagement.html',

    regions: {
        'contentRegion' : '#banner-list'
    }
});
```

Now my biggest doubt is how do I go on from here to show the banner list? I have created a collectionview and item view for the banner list, but is this program structure correct?

Comment: Sorry, but in my opinion you are a bit all over the place here: you've got a layout (which is a view) instantiating a router and also a model that generates layout view. A router should be its own module and then tell a controller what to do. The controller instantiates layouts and views using collections and models. I can only advise to (buy and) read the books offered on the Marionette website. That is money really well spent.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that too. So I read some documentations, and restarted it following the structure you are also suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

do You really need marionnete to manage your application ? especially You are beginner as me too :)
try pure backbone first. You can still use marionette as a library.
backbone MVC architecture is described perfectly on many sites.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: i know. i haven't amout of badgets to comment questions (don't know why now this allowed to me. yesterday it wasn't)

Comment: You should focus on answering questions with actual answers. It's not hard to get to the required reputation level, but you will never get there by not following the site's rules.